# simple subtraction in Visual studio with incorrect result

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

doing a simple subtraction such as this:

```
   Dim a, b As Double
   a = 81.4
   b = 76.0
   MsgBox(a - b)
```

you would expect it to result in 5.4 but instead you get 5.4000000000000001
what is going on?

Comment: Interesting in VS 2013, using C# and the immediate window: 81.4 - 76.0; results in 5.4000000000000057

Comment: This is because there is no exact representation of floating-point numbers. Have a look a this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floating point numbers, even double precision floating point numbers, are not 'real' numbers which have infinite precision.

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Bruce Dawson's blog](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)